# Notifications on Jelly Bean Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

One of the new updates on Jelly Bean is that the user can cancel notifications on the app on the list of apps.

Once the user do that, the application can't show any more notifications on the notification's bar.

I am building an app where it is higly important to show notifications, and I would like my application to know in any way if the user has change that state. Cause I would like to show a message when the user enters on the application to tell him to put it back on "on"

Anyone knows how????

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11649151/1117415

Comment: Sorry I didn´t find it.......I always try to find the solution by myself before asking here........Anyway, obviously, I didn´t check so well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do this yet. There is an issue open with google requesting the feature here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38482&q=show%20notifications&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

The status is "assigned" so it might be under development but the priority is "medium" so I wouldn't hold my breath.