# Android get Application "Show Notifications" status

Tags: android, notifications

Can i get the status of the "Show Notification" setting of my application. We can see this in application settings. Please let me know if you even did the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, there is no means in the Android SDK to get this value today.