# Read "show notifications" status of my app

Tags: android

How can I check the status of the Notifications checkmark that is on the App Info screen of my application programatically ?

This screen can be accessed by: Settings > Application Manager > [application entry]

[image: Settings Screen]

Comment: You can't . Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not available, there is a similar post that was responded to on this front. I have also looked and cannot find anything regarding this.

[Android get Application "Show Notifications" status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116133/android-get-application-show-notifications-status?rq=1)