# how to programmatically check if the app's "Show Notification" is on/off as set in "Settings"

Tags: android

How can I check the status of "Show Notification" checkbox in "Settings" programmatically. The minimum API supported by the App is 16.

The suggested duplicate question doesn't answer my question and I found one and posted below.

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if Show Notification is disabled for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573340/how-to-know-if-show-notification-is-disabled-for-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

I found what I want from this url: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38482. I duplicate the answer here:

```
public class NotificationsUtils {

    private static final String CHECK_OP_NO_THROW = "checkOpNoThrow";
    private static final String OP_POST_NOTIFICATION = "OP_POST_NOTIFICATION";

    public static boolean isNotificationEnabled() {

        AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) GlobalContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

        ApplicationInfo appInfo = GlobalContext.getContext().getApplicationInfo();

        String pkg = GlobalContext.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        int uid = appInfo.uid;

        Class appOpsClass = null; /* Context.APP_OPS_MANAGER */

        try {

            appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());

            Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

            Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
            int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);

            return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, uid, pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Just noticed from that url, the API level is 19.