# Is there an API for "users blocking our notifications" in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

As a app designer, the worst thing is having my app unstalled. Second-worst is having my notifications blocked.  If many users are blocking our app's notifications, I want to know early and often.

Seems like apps can know if they're blocked (NotificationListener?), but it's not clear how to measure percentage of users blocking my app.  I was surprised to find no existing API in Google Analytics or Android's APIs for this.

When I can't find an API for something I presume is really important, it makes me worry there's some other way to get that info that I don't know about. Is there?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#areNotificationsEnabled()) method to determine if your notifications are blocked.

Keep in mind that this only will return `false` on Kitkat or above devices - prior to that, it was not possible to determine if you blocked (even though blocking notifications was added in Jellybean MR2).

Of course, as detailed in the [What's new with Notifications I/O 2016 talk](https://youtu.be/6eFQbC5r17w?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte&t=1685), this should only be used for catching edge cases (like on a notification settings page) and not for telling the user that they must re-enable notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this setting via reflection:
[how to programmatically check if the app's "Show Notification" is on/off as set in "Settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879909/how-to-programmatically-check-if-the-apps-show-notification-is-on-off-as-set)

Comment: That's exactly what `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` does on pre-API 24 devices.