# Detect notification toggle value in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to detect the value of app notifications toggle handling for android 6.0 os in my application say "TestNotifications".

Here is sample screen shot just for reference (original screen will be of "TestNotifications" app instead of Calendar with different notifications options) :

[image]

Let's say for example, if I toggle the value of "Allow Notifications" to true then I want to detect this value in my TestNotifications application.

Is it programatically possible to do it?

I checked some of the posts but I am not able to understand :

- [How to check if my app is allowed to show notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815782/how-to-check-if-my-app-is-allowed-to-show-notification)
- [How to know if Show Notification is disabled for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573340/how-to-know-if-show-notification-is-disabled-for-my-app)
- [Android - Push Notification are ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912629/android-push-notification-are-on)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632076/6587754

Comment: @DuduLev : This does not work.