# Android get show notification state from system App info

Tags: android

How do i listen to changes in the state of show notifications settings for my application in system applications info.

I want to enable my application notification as soon as user enabled this setting.

.[image]

Comment: What is your goal?  You want to listen for notifications to be posted?

Comment: yes,as soon as user enables "show notificaions" i want to dispaly my application notification back.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question answered here: [Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

According to [this](http://youtu.be/Yc8YrVc47TI?t=48m5s), you can't detect the changing of this setting.