# How to get notified when user turn off the APP's notification drawer in Settings?

Tags: android, notifications

I've learnt that after Jelly Bean user can turn off some App's notification in Settings, see  [this](http://www.guidingtech.com/13572/disable-useless-app-notifications-android-jelly-bean/)

So I want to know if there's a way to let the App know when user turn off its notification?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application If you check the link in the last comment under the question, it's still an open issue as of May 30, 2014.

Comment: In case you didn't get the gist of what I linked in my previous comment: No, there is no way, as of yet, to determine the state of your app's Notifications Settings, let alone if it's toggled.