# Android - show notifications even if it is disabled for the application?

Tags: android, notifications, system, android-notifications

In my app if user disable *Show notification* option Android system removes all my notification. But DU Battery Saver app it still shows, here it is [image]

Please help me how to implement like this? And i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application) link as well.

Comment: I have tried this now and what I can come up with is that you does not disable Show notification on the right app. You disabled notifications on the app DU Speed Booster and what i can see is DU Battery Saver is another app meaning you must disable notification for that app instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will never be possible because if it would, the feature from Android would be unnecessary because every developer could bypass it.
And if there were any possibility I guess the Android team would fix this very soon, because it would be a bug.

And as already mentioned in the comment from [Johan Lindkvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123633/) you disabled the notifications of the wrong app.

If you still need to notify the user because of some important information, you could use a `Service`. And then use the `getApplicationContext()` to display a `Toast`. But you should include your app name in the message, so the user knows who was sending the message. 
But this is no good practice because you should use `Toast`s only if the user is in your app according to the guidelines:

> Your app should not create a dialog or toast if it is not currently on
>   screen. A dialog or toast should only be displayed as an immediate
>   response to the user taking an action inside of your app.

(https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by setting the priority to MAX?

```
final Notification.Builder notification = new Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.text))
                .setColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.yellow))) 
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small) 
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))        
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);       
mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to get Notification for app if user turned it off. Android did not exposed any api to control iit too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I understand, **but Its not possible to get Notification for app** itself is an answer.