# Android: Recognize if notifications for app disabled from apps menu

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

How can I know if the user unchecked the "Show notifications" for my app from Settings->apps->my_app?

There is this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application) but It's seems still not clear whether if there is some workaround here or even if such exist - Google will 'close it in the next update'?

[image]