# Android List of enabled notification listeners is empty (getEnabledListenerPackages)

Tags: android, push-notification

When I try to fetch the list of getEnabledListenerPackages I get an empty list.

```
NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(getContext())
```

returns null.

I know there are many apps which receive notifications what else needs to be done to get this to return a proper list.

alternatively is there any way of finding if user has disabled push for the app from settings

Comment: Hi, are you succeed in knowing if the user has disabled push notifications from settings?

Comment: hey, this post was useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/30108004/838355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by taking an alternate route, as suggested from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108004/838355)

Answer (score 1):

According to  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application/11649654#11649654) it seems that from 19+ you can know that notifications are enabled or not for your app. More precisely this is the call [NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#areNotificationsEnabled()).

Comment: this code snippet worked to solve my issue, 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30108004/838355