# how to get notification status of our android app dynamically

Tags: notifications, android-push-notification

We implemented a chat application in android ,when user don't want to get any notifications,

```
     he will turn off the notification in settings of the app ,
```

but how to get the "*status of the notification*"(on/off) in android programming in order to prevent  sending notifications to those users who turned off ,in order to save the charges which will apply to send notifications to  users....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after I had searched a lot.... I found solution to get the ***Notification status of our app*** here:
Use

```
 NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

Use NotificationManagerCompat.from(Context).areNotificationsEnabled(), from support library, to check if notifications are blocked on API 19+. The versions below API 19 will return true (notifications are enabled).

For more details go through this link :[get NotificationStatus based on version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)