# Receiver when disable/enable notification from device settings

Tags: android

I want to restore notifications when a user re-enables notifications for my app in device settings.

Is there a way I can listen to this event?

update: I have always notification in the status bar. When a user turns off notifications in the device's settings app. My notifications will be lost. I want to know when the user re-enables the notification to show my notifications again in the status bar.

Comment: are you using firebase ??

Comment: @SantanuSur yes. But I want show notification from my app right away user re-enable it in device app settings.

Comment: juat when user re-enable, u show notification thats it ryt ??

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: juat remove the token and get the token ,..during on/off !!

Comment: if you want to remove all notification try `notificationManager.cancelAll();`

Comment: No, Notification will auto cancel. I want show it again when user re-enable from device settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application Ref this

Comment: @JZM I want listen when user re-enable notification from device settings.

Comment: I got the same issue